Shiny extracted number leads to en error when using "between" function
EDIT (but not solved yet)
This following code leads to the error:

# Possible result with num_src() == 6 & num_ong() == 4
donnees = tribble(
~epci.res,~annee,~an_muta,~natloc3,~n,~pct,~total
Bordeaux Métropole,2015,FALSE,Appart,8175,0.7456220357533747,10964
Bordeaux Métropole,2015,FALSE,Maison,2789,0.2543779642466253,10964
Bordeaux Métropole,2015,TRUE,Appart,755,0.6869881710646042,1099
Bordeaux Métropole,2015,TRUE,Maison,344,0.3130118289353958,1099
Bordeaux Métropole,2016,FALSE,Appart,7968,0.742937062937063,10725
Bordeaux Métropole,2016,FALSE,Maison,2757,0.257062937062937,10725
Bordeaux Métropole,2016,TRUE,Appart,577,0.698547215496368,826
Bordeaux Métropole,2016,TRUE,Maison,249,0.3014527845036319,826
Bordeaux Métropole,2017,FALSE,Appart,10306,0.7248048385962444,14219
Bordeaux Métropole,2017,FALSE,Maison,3913,0.2751951614037556,14219
Bordeaux Métropole,2017,TRUE,Appart,922,0.5952227243382827,1549
Bordeaux Métropole,2017,TRUE,Maison,627,0.4047772756617172,1549
Bordeaux Métropole,2018,FALSE,Appart,8399,0.7325774095071959,11465
Bordeaux Métropole,2018,FALSE,Maison,3066,0.2674225904928042,11465
Bordeaux Métropole,2018,TRUE,Appart,1867,0.7194605009633911,2595
Bordeaux Métropole,2018,TRUE,Maison,728,0.2805394990366089,2595
Bordeaux Métropole,2019,FALSE,Appart,8368,0.7362308639802921,11366
Bordeaux Métropole,2019,FALSE,Maison,2998,0.2637691360197079,11366
Bordeaux Métropole,2019,TRUE,Appart,1076,0.662969808995687,1623
Bordeaux Métropole,2019,TRUE,Maison,547,0.337030191004313,1623
Bordeaux Métropole,2020,FALSE,Appart,13438,0.8117675486287302,16554
Bordeaux Métropole,2020,FALSE,Maison,3116,0.1882324513712698,16554
Bordeaux Métropole,2020,TRUE,Appart,1118,0.6901234567901234,1620
Bordeaux Métropole,2020,TRUE,Maison,502,0.3098765432098766,1620
Bordeaux Métropole,2021,FALSE,Appart,13308,0.8090461426226518,16449
Bordeaux Métropole,2021,FALSE,Maison,3141,0.1909538573773482,16449
Bordeaux Métropole,2021,TRUE,Appart,1078,0.6633846153846154,1625
Bordeaux Métropole,2021,TRUE,Maison,547,0.3366153846153846,1625
CA Rochefort Océan,2015,FALSE,Appart,709,0.1840124578250714,3853
CA Rochefort Océan,2015,FALSE,Maison,3144,0.8159875421749286,3853
CA Rochefort Océan,2015,TRUE,Appart,46,0.1957446808510638,235
CA Rochefort Océan,2015,TRUE,Maison,189,0.8042553191489362,235
CA Rochefort Océan,2016,FALSE,Appart,751,0.1932081296629792,3887
CA Rochefort Océan,2016,FALSE,Maison,3136,0.8067918703370208,3887
CA Rochefort Océan,2016,TRUE,Appart,82,0.2867132867132867,286
CA Rochefort Océan,2016,TRUE,Maison,204,0.7132867132867133,286
CA Rochefort Océan,2017,FALSE,Appart,834,0.2061804697156984,4045
CA Rochefort Océan,2017,FALSE,Maison,3211,0.7938195302843016,4045
CA Rochefort Océan,2017,TRUE,Appart,83,0.2492492492492492,333
CA Rochefort Océan,2017,TRUE,Maison,250,0.7507507507507507,333
CA Rochefort Océan,2018,FALSE,Appart,750,0.1975243613378983,3797
CA Rochefort Océan,2018,FALSE,Maison,3047,0.8024756386621017,3797
CA Rochefort Océan,2018,TRUE,Appart,119,0.2997481108312343,397
CA Rochefort Océan,2018,TRUE,Maison,278,0.7002518891687658,397
CA Rochefort Océan,2019,FALSE,Appart,742,0.1951604418726986,3802
CA Rochefort Océan,2019,FALSE,Maison,3060,0.8048395581273015,3802
CA Rochefort Océan,2019,TRUE,Appart,61,0.2663755458515284,229
CA Rochefort Océan,2019,TRUE,Maison,168,0.7336244541484717,229
CA Rochefort Océan,2020,FALSE,Appart,905,0.224009900990099,4040
CA Rochefort Océan,2020,FALSE,Maison,3135,0.775990099009901,4040
CA Rochefort Océan,2020,TRUE,Appart,36,0.2236024844720497,161
CA Rochefort Océan,2020,TRUE,Maison,125,0.7763975155279503,161
CA Rochefort Océan,2021,FALSE,Appart,1428,0.304932735426009,4683
CA Rochefort Océan,2021,FALSE,Maison,3255,0.695067264573991,4683
CA Rochefort Océan,2021,TRUE,Appart,100,0.3937007874015748,254
CA Rochefort Océan,2021,TRUE,Maison,154,0.6062992125984252,254
)

ui <- page_sidebar(
  sidebar = sidebar(
    position = 'right',
    helpText("Veuillez remplir les champs suivants :"),
    
    
    
    # Sélecteur de la source et de la variable
    selectInput(
      inputId = "src",
      label = "Source :",
      choices = c(
        "Fidéli",
        "Filocom"
      )
    ),
    selectInput(
      inputId = "var",
      label = "Indicateur :",
      choices = choix
    ),

    
    selectInput(
      inputId = "muta",
      label = "Filtrez selon la dernière année de mutation du local :",
      choices = c(
        "Ensemble des logements" = F, 
        "Logements ayant muté cette année" = T)
    ),
    
    uiOutput('an'),

    selectInput(
      inputId = "epci",
      multiple = TRUE,
      label = "EPCI(s) :",
      choices = EPCI,
      selected = "CA de La Rochelle" 
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
 
# Nom de la source
  num_src <- reactive({
    case_match(input$src, 'Fidéli' ~ 0, 'Filocom' ~ 6) |>
      as.integer()
    })

  # Numéro de l'onglet de l'indicateur sélectionné
  num_ong <- reactive({case_match(
    str_sub(input$var,1,1),
    'S' ~ 1, 'Â' ~ 2, 'D' ~ 3, 'O' ~ 4, 'N' ~ 5, 'C' ~ 6) 
  })



 # Tableau des dates min et max des 2 sources
  dates <- reactive({tribble(
    ~src, ~muta, ~y_min, ~y_max, ~intvl,
    0, c(T,F), 2015,2021,1,
    6,T,2013,2020,1,
    6,F,2014,2020,2,
    0,c(T,F), 2020,2021,1
  ) |>
      mutate(ong = case_when(
        y_min == 2020 ~ list(6L), T ~ list(1:5))) |>
      unnest(muta) |>
      unnest(ong) |> 
      filter(src == num_src() & muta == input$muta &
               ong == as.integer(num_ong()))
  })
  
y_min <- reactive({pull(dates(),y_min)})
y_max <- reactive({pull(dates(),y_max)})
intvl <- reactive({pull(dates(),intvl)})

  
  # Réglage de la barre de sélection des années
  output$an <- renderUI({
    sliderInput(
      inputId = "an",
      label = "Choisissez une période :",
      sep = '',
      step = intvl,
      min = y_min(), max = y_max(),
      value = c(y_min(), y_max())
    )
  })

 an_min <- input$an[[1]] 
 an_max <- input$an[[2]]
data <- donnees[[num_src() + num_ong()]] |> 
      filter(an_muta == input$muta  & between(annee,an_min,an_max) & #ERRORRR!!
                epci.res %in% input$epci)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

Avis : Error in filter: ℹ In argument: `an_muta == input$muta & annee >= an_min & annee <= an_max`.
Caused by error:
! `..1` must be of size 756 or 1, not size 0.

I checked to make sure that left and right between's arguments are indeed integer with str() function. I got them from a shiny input as shown above. "Shiny pipes" may have "corrupted" the data. What could explain the problem? Would you have an idea?
Hint : it worked before I added 'dates' tibble ...

Welcome to SO! It would be easier to help you if you provide a minimal reproducible example including a minimal but complete and runnable code and a snippet of your input data shared using dput() (or using some fake data or using a built-in dataset).

My guess is that the problem is not with between() but rather with an_muta == input$muta. Here you are comparing whatever is in the $an_muta element of the specified element of donnees with input$muta. If these two vectors are of different lengths you'll get the error you listed. You can narrow the problem down to this component by temporarily removing the second two clauses of your ... & ... & ... statement and seeing if you still get the error.

No, an_muta == input$muta  works (I've added more code above, it could help)

It's a "scheduling issue". With renderUI(), input$an doesn't exist when renderPlot() is called.
I just needed to add req(input$an)
at the start of my renderPlot()...
In R shiny, why am I getting an error message after making simple adaptation to renderUI?
